# GREP, command does not work as I've been reading

Tags: unix, grep

I have given an assignment and the question is:

Suppose you were working a word puzzle and needed a 5-letter word beginning with a vowel (including ‘y’) in upper- or lower-case, a lower-case ‘t’ in the third position, and ending with a lower-case ‘s’.

The remaining letters could be any character that occurs in English words, including upper and lower-case alphabetics, numbers, hyphens, etc. (We will accept the file /usr/share/dict/words as the authority on what constitutes a valid English word and what characters can appear within one.)

What grep command would you use to list the words from /usr/share/dict/words that match this requirement?

I have tried a lot of commands and I can not seem to get it. Is there any kind of hint someone could give me towards the
 answer?

Comment: Perhaps you could share with us your attempt and analysis of how it failed to meet your expectations.

Comment: _3. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._